# How to split text in 2 halves?

Tags: php, string

I've done it like so:

```
if(strlen($block_text) > 2000) {
  $half = strlen($block_text)/2;
  $second_half = substr($block_text, $half);
  $block_text = substr($block_text, 0, $half);
}
```

but the problem here is that the `$second_half` starts in the middle of a word and the `$block_text` ends in the middle of a word. Could it be possible to tweak it somehow so that the first half ends after a dot `.` ?

Comment: Find a first dot after middle of the text.

Comment: and what if there isn't a dot `.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(strlen($block_text) > 2000) {
  $half = strpos($block_text, ".",  strlen($block_text)/2);
  $second_half = substr($block_text, $half);
  $block_text = substr($block_text, 0, $half);
}
```

Now it will find the first dot after half the text.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried this and seems working well for me:

```
if ( 2000 < strlen( $block_text ) ) {
    $string_parts = explode( " ", $block_text );
    $half = join( " ", array_slice( $string_parts, 0, floor( count( $string_parts ) / 2 ) ) );
    $second_half = join( " ", array_slice( $string_parts, floor( count( $string_parts ) / 2 ) ) );
}
```

In addition to what I wrote above, in order to have even better accuracy, you may need to remove multiple space characters found in your string.